# Excel number formatting. Treat my cell as a number but leave its formatting alone! (ie Trailing 0's)

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have (what seems like it should be) a simple problem.  I need to be able to tell excel (in vba) that a cell's contents are numeric, but I don't really want to apply any formatting to it.  I need my trailing zeros left how they are.  Am I missing something incredibly simple?

**Update:**

I'm getting xml data from a query and am placing it into the spreadsheets.  But lets say one of the cells has `589.950000` I need to keep those additional zeros on display for the user (don't ask me why, they just want the precision) but excel converts it to `589.95`.  I also need for them to be able to do spreadsheet calculations on that cell (so I can't format it as text).

**Update 2:**

Further Clarification.  Lets say I have 4 values that I'm going to place into a column

```
595.56000
15.00
90.00050
1919.120000000
```

is there one numeric format that I can apply to that column that will display those exact numbers?

Comment: Excel will do calculations on a cell even if it's formatted as Text.

Comment: Not necessarily.  For example, SUM, COUNT, MAX, MIN, and some other worksheet functions that take ranges of numbers as arguments will ignore cells formatted as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with one custom format.

What you can do is make a macro that does the input for you and modifies each cell format as it puts the value into it.  You can use the Macro Recorder to get a handle on where to start with this.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even care if it is a custom format.  All I need is an option that doesn't truncate leading or trailing 0's and yet still reacts as a number (for excel formula functions.  I can't believe that there is no option for that in excel.  I have a function in my vba code that will make this work by creating a custom format based on the number length, but that implies that I have to loop through all of the cells and I was hoping to avoid that due to the sheer number of cells and the amount of time that would eat up for each run.

Comment: @Doug, yeh, if you had a narrower range of options it would be possible with custom formatting.  Excel just doesn't have a significant figure option, and I looked hard at coming up with something special, but just hit the wall everytime.  The only way I see it is to loop in some way.

Comment: I appreciate the help, it's a shame that a feature as basic as 'leave my junk alone' wasn't incorporated into excel :/

Comment: @Doug, yep, that's why some of us have to do a lot of VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to use the value of the cell as a numerical one but you don't want to change the real val of the cell ?

In vba, you can use `CInt(yourvar)` to convert a string to number. Thus, the value you get will sure be an integer.

**[edit]** Btw, if you want to display or set back the value to a cell with the format you want, you can use the `Format ( expression, [ format ] )` function of Excel vba

**[edit 2]**

As you cannot predict how many zeros you will have, i can't see any number format that would work. You'd probably better use the **Text format** as Lance Robert suggested. To use formula on text cells, you can use the `VALUE` formula to convert the cell to use it as a number. If you need it on a range, you may have to use **array formulas** like this : `{=SUM(IF(ISTEXT(A1:A4);VALUE(A1:A4);A1:A4))}`.

Please let us know if you want some help on these formulas.

Regards,

Max

Comment: Can't you use the standard Excel > Format Cell "###00.00000" ? Btw, you can use this format with the vba format function. Tell us if you want more info or if it does not answer your problem.

Comment: Well the problem is that not all cells in the column will have the same precision.

Comment: Well, you can use # when you want to display the number *only* if it is not null and you can use 0 to display a number in every case (0 or else).

Comment: The problem with that is if you use the 0 formatting character, it inserts the number of 0's that you have in the format.

So if my formatting key were 00000.00000 
and my number was 15.1500
The output would end up being 00015.15000.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
Val(Range("A1").Value)
```

Which will evalulate the text to a number

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of decimal places you need, you can use something like the following:

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0.000000"
```

I suppose you could even get fancy and check the number of trailing 0s in the code and adjust the formatting as required.

UPDATE:

Here's a VBA function that takes the number as a string and returns the appropriate NumberFormat string.

```
Private Function trailing(strNum As String) As String
'From number entered as string, returns Excel Number format to preserve trailing zeroes in decimal.
Dim decpt As Integer
Dim aftdec As Integer
Dim strTmp As String

decpt = InStr(strNum, ".")
If decpt = 0 Then
    strTmp = "0"
Else
    aftdec = Len(strNum) - decpt
    strTmp = "0."
    If aftdec <> 0 Then
        For i = 1 To aftdec
            strTmp = strTmp & "0"
        Next
    End If
End If
trailing = strTmp
End Function
```

Comment: This is an option, but one that I was hoping to avoid.  I was hoping to just set this as a format so that I didn't have to cycle through each cell (bad when there are thousands of cells).

Comment: Of course, if the desired number of trailing zeros is the same for a range of cells, you can change the format for the whole range in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe I just stumbled on this...

I know it's old but might as well give very simple answer:

Custom format and simply use @ symbol.  Will be treated as integer and left exactly as typed in to cell.